# JPA bidirectional entities: Select only a sub-set of child entities while query for Parent entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Assume that I have `Parent` that has a `Set` of `Child` Entity.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;
    //...
   
    private Integer someProperty;
}
```

I want to select list of `Parent` entities where `Child` has some specifications. For this, I use a query like this:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct p from Parent p left join p.children c where c.someProperty > ?1")
```

With this query, I have all `Parent` entities that their children have `someProperty > someValue`.

The problem is that in `service` class, when I get children of a `Parent` instance, `Hibernate` loads all the children from database while I want only children that meet that specification in the query that is a sub set of parent's children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-join-table):

```
@FilterDef(
    name="childrenFilter",
    parameters=@ParamDef(name="parameter", type="int" ))
@Entity
public class Parent {
    //...
    @FilterJoinTable(
        name="childrenFilter",
        condition="childProperty > :parameter")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
    //...
}
```

You need to enable filters if you want to use them:

```
String jpql = "select distinct p from Parent p left join p.children c where c.someProperty > ?1";
entityManager
    .unwrap( Session.class )
    .enableFilter( "childrenFilter" )
    .setParameter( "parameter", 11)
    .createQuery(jpql, Parent.class)
    .setParameter(1, 11)
    .getResultList();
```

You can disable the filter after the query with:

```
entityManager
    .unwrap( Session.class ) 
    .disableFilter( "childrenFilter" );
```

Comment: Thanks! Two questions: 1- How to implement query with filters in Spring Boot? How to enable/disable filter? For example in back-office services we don't need filter.

Comment: I don't know Spring Boot handle them out of the box. But they only work if you enable them with entity manager, so you can only enable them before running the query and disable them after